# Scribing a scroll with an enhanced Spell-Like Ability

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats, crafting

Following up on [my previous question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171055/scribing-a-scroll-with-a-spell-like-ability) regarding the scribing of Spell-Like Abilities, I'd like to know how feats that affect the SLA, such as [Intensified SLA](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/intensified-spell-like-ability-monster/), [Quicken SLA](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/quicken-spell-like-ability/), etc., affect the scribing. Unlike actual Metamagic feats, these don't affect the "spell level" of the SLA, they're simply usable 3 times per day.

For instance, would a quickened 1st level SLA count as 1st or 5th level for the purposes of scribing (and therefore, the gold cost)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic and most restrictive answer is that feats like [Intensify Spell-like Ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/intensified-spell-like-ability-monster/) and [Quicken Spell-like Ability](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/monster-feats/quicken-spell-like-ability/) can't be used during magic item creation: On [**Magic Item Creation**](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-item-creation/), in part, says, "Using metamagic feats, a caster can place spells in items at a higher level than normal." Since feats that modify spell-like abilities aren't [metamagic feats](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/FEATS/#Metamagic_Feats), they can't be used to place spells in items at a higher level than normal.

If a GM wants to shut down this line of inquiry cold then that's that. However, this GM would likely allow creatures the possess one or more feats that exactly mirror one or more metamagic feats to contribute a modified spell to the creation of a magic item at the normal increased price according to the corresponding metamagic feat. For example, this GM would likely allow a creature that possesses the feat Intensify Spell-like Ability to contribute an intensified spell to a magic item, but the magic item's creator would see that spell's spell level increased by +1 (and have to pay a correspondingly increased price) just as if a spell had been modified by the feat [Intensified Spell](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/intensified-spell-metamagic/).